# Stuck at hello world ASP.Net Core

Tags: html

I know this might be silly, but I created a new Empty ASP.Net Core project with Visual Studio 2019, added a new 'html page' item and regrdless of what is inside the body, when I run it it opens a new tab(Chrome) and prints "Hello World" every time without fail. How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>This page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello There</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any additional example page on your project ? Maybe it is detecting an example page inside your project, and therefore the project is compiling that as an index page.

Comment: No, this is the only one.

Comment: How are you returning the View from your controller ?